# I'm trying simplify my code but the answer is wrong

Tags: python

This is my code (It's right):

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    l = list(set(sorted(arr)))
    l.remove(max(l))
    print(max(l))
```

But I want do this (pythonic):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
    l = list(set(sorted(arr)))
    print(l.remove(max(l)))
```

So.. when I do this my code just print:

> print(l.remove(max(l)))
>
> None

What's the problem? I just want simplify my code.

*The task: I've a list and I want print the second maximum score.*

Comment: You're printing the return value of `list.remove()`, which is always `None`.

Comment: FYI, a `set` is generally unordered, so sorting `arr` before turning it into a `set` is rather superfluous.

Comment: Think about it: how would `l.remove(max(l))` "know" to return the next maximum value in `l`? Or what value might you even expect it to return?

Comment: Sorting takes O(n lg n) time; you can get the second (or any `k`th, for constant `k`) largest item in O(n) time using a heap instead.

Comment: What's the point of `n` in this code?

Comment: @Chepner: Explanation: Given list is [2,3,6,6,5]. The maximum score is 6, second maximum is 5 . Hence, we print 5 as the runner-up score.

Comment: @WSS Nothing uses `n`; was it supposed to be the length of `arr`?

Comment: @chepner yes it's the length of arr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the map object to a set with `set()`, convert to sorted list with `sorted()` and take the second last element with `[-2]`:

```
print(sorted(set(arr))[-2])
```

---

In my opinion, this is more Pythonic than removing the max and then printing the new max as it is clearer and achieved in less steps.

Comment: I'm trying this but if I've this elements in my list: [2,3,6,6,5] my stdout is: 3

Comment: @WSS My bad, please try again!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html). The `list.remove` method is one that modifies the list *in-place*. That is to say, it modifies the list that you call it on, instead of returning a new one with the change you want.

Since this function returns nothing, printing `l.remove()` gives you "None". To print the list with the element removed, you'll have to stick with your original code.

Comment: Thank you man, I read so.. make sense th return give me 'none'

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [heap](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html) instead of sorting. You can build a heap in O(n) time
and return the `k`th largest item (for any constant `k`) in O(n) time as well; sorting takes O(n lg n) time.

```
import heapq

n = int(input())
arr = [int(x) for x in input.split()]
heapq.heapify(arr)   # In-place; does not return the heapified list.
print(heapq.nlargest(2, arr)[-1])
```

Comment: A bit more context is welcome. What is a heap? (As it's not a day-to-day standard type.) What are its benefits over OP's approach, and so on. Also, `map` returns an iterator so `list()` is required I think.

Comment: @WSS A simple comment would have sufficed; no need to provide cryptic links to a screen shot.